# Kubenertes VerticalPodAutoscaler doesn't scale

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, metrics, scaling

I have a RabbitMQ service and need it to scale vertically (HPA is not compatible with my system)
I'm configuring resources relatively low to test the scalability first.

**I want:**

1. The pod to start with CPU 500m & memory 500Mi (specified by `minAllowed`)
2. If the pod used any more than 222m of CPU or 222Mi of RAM, AutoScaler will create another pod with a higher SPEC and replace the old pod with it. (by `target`)
3. If the consumption keeps increasing, AutoScaler will create higher SPEC pods until the
   SPEC hits 50000m CPU and 3Gi RAM.  (by `upperBound`)
4. The AutoScaler should be responsive as the metrics are checked 60 times/minute for sudden increments of resource consumption.  (by `recommender-interval`)

But it doesn't work as my expectation:
When the pod consumes more than 222m of CPU, the AutoScaler doen't create new pod with higher SPEC.

**My configs for deployment and VPA:**

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq-service
  labels:
    app: rabbitmq-service
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: rabbitmq-service
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: rabbitmq-service
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: rabbitmq-container
        image: rabbitmq:3-management
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
          - containerPort: 5672
          - containerPort: 15672
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 500m
            memory: 500Mi
---
apiVersion: autoscaling.k8s.io/v1beta2
kind: VerticalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq-service
  namespace: default
spec:
  targetRef:
    apiVersion: "apps/v1"
    kind: Deployment
    name: rabbitmq-service
    namespace: default
  updatePolicy:
    updateMode: Recreate
  resourcePolicy:
    containerPolicies:
      - containerName: "*"
        minAllowed:
          cpu: 500m
          memory: 500Mi
        controlledResources: ["cpu", "memory"]
status:
  recommendation:
    containerRecommendations:
    - containerName: "*"
      target:
        cpu: 222m
        memory: 222Mi
      upperBound:
        cpu: 50000m
        memory: 3Gi
  containers:
  - args:
    - recommender-interval=60*time.Minute
```

Thank you for reading all of this.

Comment: In the YAML file ,  At “updateMode:”, Can you try by replacing  “Recreate” with “Auto”.
Please refer to the VPA docs below 
[VPA1](https://www.kubecost.com/kubernetes-autoscaling/kubernetes-vpa/) and [VPA2](https://www.densify.com/kubernetes-autoscaling/kubernetes-vpa)

Comment: Is the above comment help full and issue resolved?

Comment: Thanks for helping @HemanthKumar. Unfortunately, that doesn't work. The pod was not re-create, too

Comment: How did you resolve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

GKE sets the minimum replicas for the VPA updater to 2.  Since your deployments sets replicas to 1, VPA will not perform any updates and you can only receive recommendations.

Assuming you are on GKE 1.22 or later, you can set the `minReplicas` property in your VPA spec:

```
apiVersion: autoscaling.k8s.io/v1beta2
kind: VerticalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq-service
  namespace: default
spec:
  targetRef:
    apiVersion: "apps/v1"
    kind: Deployment
    name: rabbitmq-service
    namespace: default
  updatePolicy:
    updateMode: Auto
    minReplicas: 1
  resourcePolicy:
    containerPolicies:
      - containerName: "*"
        minAllowed:
          cpu: 500m
          memory: 500Mi
        controlledResources: ["cpu", "memory"]
```